# Thread crashed with locked Mutex

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, mutex

There is scenario, I have two threads both are using same mutex. One thread locked the mutex and crashed. What would be the mutex state? Is it still locked and second thread never own that mutex? Means a deadlock situation?

Edit - Also explain a case of pthread on Linux systems

Comment: Please provide additional information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you haven't specified what OS, I'll tell you what happens in Win32.

In Win32, the second thread would get WAIT_ABANDONED when it goes to wait on the mutex owned by a thread that has terminated. **Note that receiving WAIT_ABANDONED means the second thread has received the mutex, so there won't be a deadlock.** The second thread should detect the WAIT_ABANDONED result and verify that the resource protected by the mutex is in a valid state. If it can detect corruption and does not detect any, it is safe to proceed. If not, it's a good idea to raise an error of some sort.

With some implementations of a mutex there is no way to detect that the thread owning it has terminated, and you end up with a deadlock.

With some implementations of a mutex there is a way to detect what the owning thread is, figure out that the owning thread has terminated, and then take ownership of the mutex.

Comment: in some implementations you can define waiting time or you create your own wrapper-method... anyway, thread suspending have no effect on mutex\semaphore in classic implementation so it's good idea to check waiting time and raise timeout exception or resume execution.

Comment: Sorry for half question. This is on Windows OS and also like to know the other OS behavior. Gabe: If it’s always get the WAIT_ABANDONED then easily can be handled. Again, is there deadlock?
How we detect the owner thread is crashed. Joonas Pulakka:
Just assume thread crashed with NULL. Means no exception or not any acknowledgement.

Answer (score 2):

That certainly depends on (at least) two things:

- How the mutex is implemented, and
- How the thread crashes (does it throw an exception, or does it just "disappear").

For instance, in Java's `synchronized` blocks are guaranteed to be released when the "thread is done with the object" - whatever that means (see [link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)). According to [this](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) article:

> Stopping a thread causes it to unlock all the monitors that it has locked.

Ok, `stop()`ing the thread releases the monitors, but what if a thread just somehow disappears, is it then "done with the object"?  I don't see this documented anywhere. But it's obvious that *someone* must release locked mutexes, or otherwise they'll deadlock; perhaps some mutexes or environments include mechanisms that release mutexes automatically if the thread, who locked them, becomes nonexistent.

Another example: [java.util.concurrent.Lock](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) docs recommend using a `finally` statement to release the lock so that whatever happens with the executing thread, the lock would get released. But, if the thread disappears before that `finally` statement gets executed, then the lock never gets released and a deadlock indeed occurs.  Of course, threads shouldn't "disappear" just like that.

Quite a good question!

Comment: question is good but each implementation has their own mechanism and solution to solve described problem but we could only guessing what author means :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032%28VS.85%29.aspx
MSDN also says it release the mutex and waiting threads get the WAIT_ABANDONED status.